# All social login

Tags: social-media, social-login

Is there any API available for connecting to all possible social networks (mainly facebook, linkedin, twitter, github, bitbucket, codeplex, stackexchange, google code)

I am basically looking for one stop website which can provide me logins with all the above website, for eg.http://www.oneall.com

Is there any website which provides all of this??

Answer (score 1):

There's no service that will offer authentication for every social network. Some popular ones besides Oneall are Gigya, OmniAuth, and LoginRadius.